# Разархивировать папку из zip файла

Tags: rar

У меня есть папка objvar - которая находится в rar файле . Всё что находится в этой папке - надо разархивировать например(WinRar *py /directory). Как это сделать через бат-файл использую команды
?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560983/extract-a-rar-file-using-a-batch-file

Comment: У вас в названии вопроса zip, а в самом вопросе rar. Определитесь.

Comment: Еще бы неплохо определиться с используемым архиватором, а потом прочитать по нему справку...